# List image paths of multiple formats in a Kaggle Dataset

Tags: python, data-science, kaggle

How to form a list of images of multiple formats in a Kaggle dataset where the image paths are like?
Working in Kaggle I wanted to convert the image paths into the list so that I can store and perform operations but couldn't find a proper image traversing Algo to give me the required list result.

Tree for the image is:

```
|-data
   |-images
        |-ID0
          |--- img4tgh4r3.jpg
          |--- img324633.png
          |
          .
          .
        |-ID1
        .
        .
```

I tried using `ls -a` but how do you convert this structure and save it into a data type to reuse it.

```
import os
  

path = "/"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
  
print("Files and directories in '", path, "' :") 
  
# print the list
print(dir_list)
```

This only lists the directories but not all the image types.

Comment: The question lacks clarity and is difficult to understand. The acceptance of the single answer suggests that OP was likely asking 'how to create a list of files from multiple sub-directories?' If that is indeed the case: (a) 'data-sciente' and 'kaggle' tags are irrelevant (it makes no difference that the files came from Kaggle). (b) the title is misleading (c) it is very likely a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using either `os` or `glob` modules in Python. I would suggest using `glob` as it facilitates more functionality w.r.t filenames in various scenarios.

**SAMPLE CODE**:

```py
import glob
from tqdm import tdqm

# The required file extensions
fetch_formats = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']

# Declare an empty list for storing the file names
img_list = list()

# State the directory of interest
path = working_dir + "images/**/*."

# Fetch each type of file from the given directory
for ff in tqdm(fetch_formats, desc="Fetching the filenames"):
    img_list.extend(list(glob.glob(path+ff)))

print(f"\nTotal number of images: {len(img_list)}")
```

**NOTE**:

- Usage of `tqdm` is for generating the progress bar and can be avoided
- The `*.png* would imply any filename ending with` .png`
- The `dir\**\*.png` would imply any sub-directory inside `dir` which contains files whose names end with `.png`

Check out the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for more information